# Probability of edges in Graph

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory

I have given a random graph G(n, p) with n = 5000 vertices and an edge probability of p = 0.004.

I calculated the expected number of edges which is (0.004 * maximum number of possible edges)
$pE = 0.004 * n(n-1)/2 = 0.004 * 5000 * 4999 * \frac{1}{2} = 49990$

So the expected degree of a vertex should be

$\frac{pE}{n} = 9.998 \approx 10$

right?

I wonder what would be the probability to find m = 100 edges in the graph?
And what is the probability, that a vertex in the graph has a degree of one?

I am quite new to probability-theory it would be great if someone could help me.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vertex can have degree at most $4999$. The probability of having degree 0 is $(1-p)^{4999}$. In general the probability of having degree $k$ is $\binom{4999}{k}p^k(1-k)^{4999-k}$ because we have to choose $k$ edges that are included in which case $4999-k$ edges are not included. The expected degree of a vertex is therefore
$$\sum_{k=0}^{4999}{k\binom{4999}{k}p^k(1-p)^{4999-k}}=4999p\sum_{k=1}^{4999}{\frac{4998!}{(k-1)!(4998-(k-1))!}p^{k-1}(1-p)^{4998-(k-1)}}$$
and this is also equal to $4999p=19.996$.

The probability that the graph has exactly $100$ edges is
$$\binom{\binom{5000}{2}}{100}p^{100}(1-p)^{\binom{5000}{2}-100}$$
which is extremely small (about $9.292984327\times 10^{-21203}$).

The probability that a given vertex has degree exactly $1$ is $4999p(1-p)^{4998}$.